# How to use a validator in Laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0. I want using a laravel validator where my MENU_NAME column in 'dbo.MS_MENU' is unique. I am using sql server database. I have made a validator code like in the below, but I still got an error

> QueryException in Connection.php line 624:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_MS_MENU'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MS_MENU'. The duplicate key value is (Role). (SQL: EXEC dbo.M_INSERT_MENU_PARENT '0', '121', 'Role', 'Menu coba', '0', 'SDF')

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'MENU_NAME' => 'unique:dbo.MS_MENU']);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect ('Menu')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: i think the error came from DB side..

Comment: if i change 'unique:dbo.MS_MENU' to 'required' it's work. do you think it's because of DB?

Comment: Then we need to specify the condition here when it will be as unique one.

Answer (score 0):

pls try with this one

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'MENU_NAME' => 'unique:dbo.MS_MENU,MENU_NAME']);
```

You need to use table name and also column name

Comment: it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Hello check following code,

```
 //Validation using ajax    
public function checkvalidation(Request $request) {

    $data['SUCC_FLAG'] = 0;
    $formdata = $request->only('uname', 'umail', 'dob', 'cno', 'pwd', 'cpwd');
    $rules = ['uname' => 'required|min:2|alpha', 'umail' => 'required|email', 'dob' => 'required|date', 'cno' => 'required|digits:10', 'pwd' => 'required|min:3|max:6', 'cpwd' => 'required|same:pwd'];
    $validator = Validator::make($formdata, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $data['msg'] = $validator->errors();
    } else {
        $data['SUCC_FLAG'] = 1;
        $data['msg'] = "success";
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

this is sample code i use for my project you have to change according to your use or project.

for use validator you have to include **use Validator;** in header

i hope this works for you